# Parallel Program Construct - Computer Architecture

Tags: parallel-processing, cpu-architecture

I'm not sure whether this is a correct place for me to ask, it's about Computer Architecture. But I'm desperate so please pardon me.

Does anyone understand this parallel program? I can't proceed to answer my assignment because of this.

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 2):

This means that each instruction between `PARBEGIN` and `PAREND` should be executed in parallel and the whole block will terminate when every single `proc_k` has terminated.

So in other words, the program will continue after `PAREND` as soon as `proc_1` to `proc_k` (executed concurrently) terminated.

Comment: thank you.... i think i'm getting something, maybe i can continue to answer my assignment. Thank's a lot bro

Answer (score 0):

It means that Proc_1 to Proc_k execute concurrently. For example, if each needs 2 seconds to be done, the total time to execute Proc_1 to Proc_k is 2 seconds, not 2*k seconds.